# Spark transformation schema infer warning (pyspark)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to read a tsv data(delimiter is '\t') but when I make a transformation for it the warn
"WARN CSVHeaderChecker: CSV header does not conform to the schema." happen

my tsv file's first column name is a black column so I make code like this

```
        data_frame = (
            self.spark.read.csv(path=input_file,
            sep="\t",
            comment='#',
            inferSchema=True,
            header=True).withColumnRenamed("_c0", "my_new_col")
        )
```

after this process and I acted "show" action.

then the spark show me the above error

**WARN CSVHeaderChecker: CSV header does not conform to the schema.
Expected: _c0 but found:**

it is a just warn not error but I want to solve this

---edited---

I found why this happend

becaute header read ""(null) to ""(null) and schema read null to "_c0"

but when I tried `printschema()`

```
root
 |-- my_new_col: string (nullable = true)
```

schema was changed but when I call action the warning msg always happen
and in the msg schema is still "_c0"

I can't understand why this happen

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula No I'm using local mode

Comment: Why you have this part: `.withColumnRenamed("_c0", "my_new_col")` ?

What is the header of your tsv file ?

Comment: @btbbass My tsv file have a lots of columns and it is made by padnas dataframe.
The file's first column is  "" (null) because tsv file index name is not made in pandas df so it saved as "".
When spark read tsv file with option header=True ""(null) is allocated to "_c*"